# How to fix SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop in Python app

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

print(f"Select Operation")
print(f"1) Addition")
print(f"2) Subtraction")
print(f"3) Multiplication")
print(f"4) Divition")

while True:
    choice = input("Enter choice (1, 2, 3, or 4): ")

if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
    num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))

    if choice == '1':
        print(f" {num1} + {num2} = ", add(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '2':
        print(f" {num1} - {num2} = ", subtract(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '3':
        print(f" {num1} * {num2} = ", multiply(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '4':
        print(f" {num1} / {num2} = ", divide(num1, num2))
    
    next_calculation = input("Let's do another calculation? (yes/no): ")
    if next_calculation == "no":
        break
    
else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

I need help understanding why the `break` after `if next_calculation == "no"`: always spits out `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop`. Please help me fix it so the simple app will run.

Comment: If you intend that that `break` *be* inside a loop, you need your indentation to reflect that. Python is an indentation-sensitive language.

Comment: You need to indent the entire `if` block if you meant for it (and the break inside of it) to be inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Everything after the `choice = input(...)` line is not indented far enough; Python requires the indentation to be done in a very specific way since it's the only thing that controls which code belongs to which block/scope. So, it seems that you need to educate yourself on how whitespace and indentation works in Python, since it's such a fundamental aspect of the language that needs to be learned on day 1.

Answer (score 2):

Python blocks are designated by indentation, and your `break` command is not inside the `while` loop.

To fix this, you need to indent the entire `if`/`else` block so it is inside the `while` loop.

```py
while True:
    choice = input("Enter choice (1, 2, 3, or 4): ")

    if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
        num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))

        if choice == '1':
            print(f" {num1} + {num2} = ", add(num1, num2))
        elif choice == '2':
            print(f" {num1} - {num2} = ", subtract(num1, num2))
        elif choice == '3':
            print(f" {num1} * {num2} = ", multiply(num1, num2))
        elif choice == '4':
            print(f" {num1} / {num2} = ", divide(num1, num2))
    
        next_calculation = input("Let's do another calculation? (yes/no): ")
        if next_calculation == "no":
            break
    
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```